# Extract month over several years with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

Extracting month in lubridate is straightforward: `month(some_date)`, and this gives `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5...`

But what if I need to determine month number over several years to get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16...` ? Is there a way to reach this in `lubridate` (or with R base) ? Thank you

I tried this

```
Day <- c('2015/01/01', '2015/03/01', '2015/07/25', '2016/03/05', '2016/11/28')
Day <- date(Day)
Month <- Day - min(Day)
Month <- ((Month/ddays(1))/30.41)+1
Month <- trunc(Month)
```

but it obviously gives a poor approximation of the month (`1 2 7 15 23` --March 1st, 2015 being considered as belonging to month #2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is substract the first year from the year of the date and multiply that by 12 and add that to the output of `month(Day)`. This will add `0` for the first year, `12` for the second year and so on.

Using:

```
month(Day) + (year(Day) - min(year(Day)))*12
```

gives:

```
[1]  1  3  7 15 23
```

In base R you could do it as follows (as also suggested by @DavidArenburg):

```
mnths <- as.POSIXlt(Day)
mnths$mon + 1 + (mnths$year - min(mnths$year)) * 12
```